Minyan with no Yisraelim— who to call up to the Torah?
I was in shul and there was a minyan for Shabbat Mincha. However, the minyan only consisted of Kohanim and Leviim (no Yisraelim present). Who should be called to the Torah and what’s the order? Sources would be helpful.

Cf. this question
